# How to clean up (remove) all old system ZFS snapshots?

Tags: 21.10, zfs, snapshot

Every time I install or update software, a snapshot is being created in the zfs rpool, and occasionally in the bpool.  After I confirm that I am still able to boot and everything is working, I wanted to go back and free up space taken by hundreds of these little snapshots.  My understanding was that I could do this with the command:

```
sudo zsysctl service gc --all -vv
```

However, after running this command and a lot of verbose output, when I see what snapshots are left using `zfs list -t snapshot` it appears that nothing was removed!  I went back and looked at the output of the garbage collection command above (`sudo zsysctl...`), and I see tons of message which say one of the following:

> Keeping as snapshot rpool/USERDATA/michael_xxxxxx@autozsys_xxxxxx is associated to a system snapshot
>
> Keeping rpool/USERDATA/root_xxxxxx@autozsys_xxxxxx as it's in the last 20 snapshots

Is there some reason I shouldn't be deleting old snapshots to free up space?  And if so, how can I actually do it?  I can destroy individually snapshots using `zfs destroy rpool/USERDATA/michael_xxxxxx@autozsys_xxxxxx`, but there are too many for this to be practical.

Comment: Can you explain from which command the message came from? Did you try `zfs destroy  rpool/USERDATA/michael_xxxxxx@autozsys_xxxxxx` ?

Comment: @freezed I have updated the question to address these.

Comment: Ubuntu tools for `zfs` are still under development and I am not well informed… Is the use of `zsys` mandatory or you just need to destroy snapshots?

Answer (score 1):

ZFS snapshots cannot be destroyed if:

- hold (see: [`zfs-hold`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man8/zfs-hold.8.html) manpage)
- used (i.e. by a [`send`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man8/zfs-send.8.html) / [`receive`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man8/zfs-receive.8.html))

To remove all snapshots without age selection, run this loop:

```bsh
for snap in $(zfs list -rt snap -Ho name <POOL>); do zfs destroy ${snap} && echo "${snap}: DESTROYED";done
```

You can adjust the dataset targeted by setting `<POOL>`, i.e. : `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_644ww7/var/log`